# When to use __() and esc_html_e?

Tags: wordpress

Can anyone explain why I would use [`__()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/) over [`esc_html_e()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html_e)?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`__()` is primarily for simple text that doesn't contain markup that needs to be escaped. It differs from `_e()` in that the former *returns* the translated text while the latter *echoes* the translated text.

`esc_html_e()` and `esc_html__()` are similar, but they are used for strings that do contain markup. They each escape the provided string, and then call on their corresponding `_e()` or `__()` counterparts depending on which one you use.

Escaping HTML is necessary if you're accepting strings provided from user input. XSS attacks are probably the most common types of attacks on sites that accept user input and render it on the page. An attacker can easily provide `<script>` tags and execute arbitrary Javascript on your page if the input is not properly cleaned or escaped.

Answer (score 9):

Just like the docs state, `esc_html_e()` retrieves a translated string, escapes it, and **echoes** the result. `__()` **returns** a translated string. [The source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/l10n.php#L0) for each of these functions makes this crystal clear:

```
function __( $text, $domain = 'default' ) {
    return translate( $text, $domain );
}

function esc_html_e( $text, $domain = 'default' ) {
    echo esc_html( translate( $text, $domain ) );
}
```

Comment: How did this answer get 9 votes? adds no value, the OP clearly is confused by the docs and the docs don't clearly indicate when to use one function over the other one.

Answer (score 0):

As for the purpose of esc_html_e(), as I understand it, is to prevent weird characters from translated strings (not the original ones you see in the code).

But _e() is just for translating, without any escape.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple Devs. If you want to echoes or print the translated string,you can use esc_html_e & if you don't want to print that translated string & only want to return its value, you can use __().

You can take reference from [esc_html_e](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html_e/) & [__()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html__/) for more info.